# content div always to take 100% screen height with css

Tags: css

I have the following webpage.
[image]

I am trying to get the blue red and white gradient to fill the entire height of the screen. Currently I have both flags on either side of the content container, all of them are surrounded by a main container.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( $blueToRed); 
  background: -o-linear-gradient($blueToRed);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($blueToRed); 
  background: linear-gradient($blueToRed);
   margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

is inside of firstContain

```
.firstContain{
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  background: #FFF;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

I am trying to get contain to be 100% height, but I add that and it doesn't move. I thought the 99999 margin padding trick would work, and it did, but then I lost some css that made it work. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance for the advice in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Assuming `.container` is a direct child of `body`, you probably also need `html,body,.container { height: 100%; }` But hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `vh` unit.

```
.container{
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `height: 100%` in both your `html, body, .container` in your styles like this:

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  border-right: 4px solid white;
  background: #333;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <div class="container">
          <p>Website Content</p>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, maybe you can go with

```
min-height: 100%;
```

in your container css, since there are no elements in the page to cover the height. So, min-height should do the work for you!